# Using 来る for product release

Tags: verbs, english-to-japanese

Is 来る strictly for coming to a physical location, or can it be used to describe a product a product release.

For example:

> 来月映画は来ます。

> The movie will be coming out next month.

> これは先月来た映画の写真です。

> This is a photo of a movie that came out last month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is 来る strictly for coming to a physical location[?]"

The answer to this part of the question is no, of course not. Google/Oxford Dictionary:

> 近づいてここに至る、届く。「いつかきた町」「手紙が―」「中村から連絡が―」。こちらに通ずる。
> 「山村に電灯がきた」

"[C]an it be used to describe a product a product release[?]"

Yes, it works but 来る is not the best word for contexts involving movies. It is not uncommon that 来る collocates with games. People often say things like「ガンダムのゲームが来るぞ！」 But with movies, you got better word choices such as 「上映」「公開」「封切る」(the last one often occurs in the passive 封切られる. Please see @aguijonazo's comments)

> その映画は来月上映されます。

> その映画は来月公開されます。

If it is music, 「リリース」is the most common word, and yes it came from "release". リリース also works with software and research reports.

Comment: 封切られる is often used for movies, too.

Comment: @aguijonazo I didn't know that word. Thank you!

Comment: It is used in passive (封切られる) with the movie being the subject/topic. It’s rarely used in active with the movie being the object. The noun form is 封切り.

Comment: @aguijonazo Very helpful. Thanks again! I looked it up after you mentioned it and the word appears to be used differently from 「上映」「公開」. Your explanation helps clarify its usage.

Comment: 上映 doesn’t necessarily mean the first time (“premiere”), whereas 封切り (lit. opening of an envelope) definitely does. 公開 implies it when used for movies.